# How to loop through an array of different objects in Java using the enhanced for loop

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an array of objects of classes Car, Bicycle, and Van. I want to iterate through all objects and execute the `go()` method. `go()` for one class looks like this.

```
public class Van extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public void go() {
        System.out.println("Van started");
    }
}
```

Each of these classes inherits the Vehicle class. So, when I initialized an array of type `Vehicle[]`, it worked without a problem.

Now I want to do the same with an array of `Object[]`. But as the objects are of different types, I get an error asking to cast the x to the relevant datatype (in this case Car, Van, or Bicycle). I tried using the `x.getClass()` but it gives me answers as class Car, class Bicycle, etc. When I try to execute `go()` method, I get an error saying `The method go() is undefined for the type Class<capture#3-of ? extends Object>`

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Car car = new Car();
        Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle();
        Van van = new Van();

        Object[] racers = {car, bicycle, van};  

        for(Object x : racers) {
            System.out.println(x.getClass()); 

            x.getClass().go();  // error - The method go() is undefined for the type Class<capture#3-of ? extends Object>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do all your classes extend `Vehicle`? If yes why not use `Vehicle[]` instead of `Object[]`?

Comment: Could you cast each `x` to a `Vehicle`?  (The _class_ of `x` does not have a method, it is `x` that has the methods!)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Yes. I did it using `Vehicle[]` and it worked. But now I want to do it with `Object[]`

Comment: @ariels it worked when I used `((Vehicle) x).go()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Car car = new Car();
        Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle();
        Van van = new Van();

        Object[] racers = {car, bicycle, van};  

        for(Object x : racers) {
            System.out.println(x.getClass()); 

            ((Vehicle) x).go();  // this is the only change I made
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would have worked

```
    Vehicle[] racers = {car, bicycle, van};  
    for (Vehicle x : racers) { ... x.go();
```

Dynamic detection does works too. You could use the modern `Stream<?>`.

```
    Object[] racers = {car, bicycle, van};  

    Arrays.stream(racers)
       .filter(r -> r instanceOf(Vehicle)
       .map(Vehicle.class::cast)
       .forEach(r -> {
            r.go(); ...
       };
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the "instanceof" keyword

```
    Object o = "testString";

    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        System.out.println("is Integer");
        return
    }

    if (o instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("is String");
        return;
    }
```